Scope of for loop counter in Visual Basic
Consider the following
Dim nofTries As Integer
For nofTires = 1 To 5
    If (condition) Then Exit For
Next 

Where due to a typo the loop counter is different than the variable declared. Yet, despite the "option explicit" on-setting, NO compiler warning or error was given, and this acted as if:
Dim nofTries As Integer
For nofTires As Integer = 1 To 5
    If (condition) Then Exit For
Next 

Is there an explanation for why the compiler took it upon itself to assume a type instead of giving an error?

This question has nothing to do with variable scope. It's about type inference. Variable scope would come into the issue if you tried to use nofTires after the next statement.

Option Explicit is irrelevant here. Since .NET Framework 1.1, the For statement itself is considered a declaration if the specified variable is not already declared. Option Strict is the relevant one here because, without type inference, you would need to specify the data type of the variable being declared. With type inference, you don't need an As clause if the type can be inferred from the initialising expression. Because 1 is an Integer, the variable is inferred to be type Integer.

This has to do with OPTION INFER being ON. Turn it off and the desired compiler error will appear. The source of the misunderstanding for me was this option doesn't really exist in VBA, but also that it seems to be on by default where off seems more reasonable.

Not only with Option Infer being on, but also the fact that a variable declaration is allowed in the For statement. If you had nofTires = 1 somewhere else, that would still be an undeclared variable error, as opposed to declaring a new variable with an inferred type like it happens in the For loop.

Having Option Infer Off by default is absolutely not reasonable. Type inference was introduced specifically to support LINQ and is required in certain LINQ scenarios.

Yes, this is an unfortunate result of combining Option Explicit with Option Infer.
However, I think it's a mistake to read from this that you should avoid Option Infer. This option enables some really nice things in modern VB.Net, especially (but not exclusively) around Linq. You really do still want Option Infer set On (as well as Explicit) in most scenarios.
Traditional For loops are an unfortunate case, because they let you use the loop to declare the variable to satisfy Option Explicit, and then Option Infer can let you omit the type definition, so the syntax appears to "just use the variable", even if you typed it wrong... even if on close examination we see the variable is both actually declared, and also given a specific type via inference.

The trick is people tend to prefer less/shorter code. Why type more? And so anyone who has worked with modern VB.Net for any meaningful length of time will prefer to idiomatically write the loop without a separate line to define the variable, like this:
For nofTires As Integer = 1 To 5
    If (condition) Then Exit For
Next 

Note the variable name is still incorrect, but it only matters inasmuch as you use the same name (right or wrong) consistently within the loop. If you then tried to use the "correct" nofTries within that loop, the code would fail because the variable was not declared. This would be give the programmer a chance to correct things. So we also see the extra line to declare the variable is not just extra typing or personal preference, but this also actively makes your code more fragile.
Additionally, users of modern idiomatic VB.Net tend to have fewer traditional For loops in the first place, preferring instead to use either For Each or a linq operation, meaning this issue doesn't come up as much as you might think.

I do wonder if you can have a compiler (or analyzer) warning (not error) for code where the variable defined in a For Loop is never used... but there are legitimate practical reasons to do this as well, where the number of iterations is what's important and the index value of each iteration is not needed.

Thanks., that is interesting, as I didn't know anything about LINQ. My intent was to know how many the loop iterated and I was simply amazed to see that the counter was always zero after the loop exit, until I realized the unusual typo. after that I wasted almost an hour guessing my way around to see why option explicit was not working as I expected.
